# Magento 2 when I click on frontend my account cannot open and it shows error

Tags: magento2, frontend, helper, exception

[image]

I am facing this issue.

> My XML file is `app/code/Prayag/Module/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
   <referenceContainer name="content">
       <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  name="order_total" template="Prayag_Module::orders.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="order_total_sidebar" template="Prayag_Module::orders.phtml">
</block>
</referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="content">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="cart_total_sidebar" template="Prayag_Module::cart_view.phtml">
</block>
</referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

> My phtml file is `app/code/Prayag/Module/view/frontend/templates/orders.phtml`

```
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerID = $customerSession->getCustomerId();

$order = $this->helper('Prayag\Module\Helper\Data')->getCollection($customerID);

foreach($order as $items){ ?>
<span>IncrementId :</span><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('sales/order/history'); ?>"><?php echo $items->getIncrementId(); ?></a><br>
<?php
echo "<b>Subtotal :</b>". $items->getSubtotal(). '<br/>';
echo "<b>Order Status :</b>". $items->getStatus(). '<br/>';
echo "<b>Date :</b>". $items->getCreatedAt().'<br/>';

}
```

> And my helper file is `app/code/Prayag/Module/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php
namespace Prayag\Module\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
public function __construct(
\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
) {
$this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
}
public function getCollection($customerID)
{
$collection = $this->orderFactory->create()->getCollection()->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')
->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id',$customerID);
$collection->setPageSize(5)->setCurPage(1);
return $collection;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your log files and browser console error messages. Try giving proper file permissions too

Comment: no I didn't check it. how to check that ??

Comment: Check Magento log files in Magento_Directory/var/log/exception.log/debug.log/system.log. Server error log files /var/log/apache2/error_log. Inspect your browser to open the developer console where you can find the errors

Comment: still it's showing errors

Comment: What error are you finding in the log files with regards to this module

Comment: [2019-04-02 10:00:44] main.CRITICAL: Class Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Magento\\Store\\Model\\Store\\Interceptor does not exist at /var/www/html/prayag/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19)"} []

Comment: Run php bin/magento setup:upgrade, php bin/magento setup:di:compile, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f with write permissions to var, pub and generated folders

Comment: thank you sir you are giving your valuable knowledge but still it is not giving me proper output. It's throws errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please check `Pragayag\Module\Helper\Data.php` file. The error says `getLabel()` method doesn't exist. So please check it.

Comment: thank you for replying Mr. Raj Mohan. but in my code it is

<?php
namespace Prayag\Module\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
public function __construct(
\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
) {
$this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
}
public function getCollection($customerID)
{
$collection = $this->orderFactory->create()->getCollection()->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')
->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id',$customerID);
$collection->setPageSize(5)->setCurPage(1);
return $collection;
}
}
?>

Comment: So have you deployed the files?

Comment: please edit question and add your code there

Comment: There is no method getLabel() in your Helper class.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Command:-**

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session generated/code

sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex

sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: thanks for taking interest in my question.
but I got white blank page after running those commands.

Comment: error reporting enable in app/bootstrap.php line no. 12